# Use google by default in surfraw

Tags: command-line

How can I have `surfraw` use google as a default search engine?

Or how could I shorten `surfraw google foo` to `surfraw g foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `SURFRAW_customsearch_provider=google`.

Then use: `sr S foo`

If setting via a shell variable, make sure to `export` it.